# How to append to Event Attendee list using workflow

Tags: workflow, string, workflow-lookup, variable

On a Sharepoint 2010 workflow, on List B, I want to look up the Attendees on a particular event in List A, append that list of users with the user who Created the list item in List B (CurrentItem:CreatedBy), and then Update the event in List A with the new list of Attendees.

I am not having trouble with targeting the correct lists. That is working fine. I am specifically having trouble with which format my variables should be in (string?) and what format (Return field as) I should use for my look ups, in order to correctly do the append, and then the update. I'm able to update the Attendees with just the CurrentItem:Createdby but it removes all of the existing Attendees. This is a sort of RSVP system.

Everything I do returns this workflow error:
Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type.

If it is relevant I must use a 2010 workflow, and am working within SharePoint 2013. I also have User Profiles configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update one field with all the attendees You can turn on "Append text" in the library setting for a multi line field. You then should be able to "set field in current" item to Current Item modified or created and it will append the new name. If you are updating a list with a new row for each attendee then use the "Create item" and find the list.. When doing this use current item id field for the lookup fields. Hope this helps. Feel free to email me if you need additional help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I ended up returning all of my look ups as String.I figured out this returns the attendees in a nice string of login ids separated by semicolons. And then when appending them together I was running into problems with adding the semicolon between the current list of attendees and the new CurrentItem:Created by employee, so I tried something which might seem silly, but it worked. I made a new variable just to hold the semicolon as a string, and then added all three variables together in the String builder. It looks something like the attachment. [image]